# React js can't call "componentDidMount"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for building a minting website i need to get totalMintedAmount at start of react js app but i can't call "componentDidMount" function at beginning i looked for docs but couldnt find what im doing wrong, here's error and code below, thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
  function getSupplyAtStart(){
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      if(ethereum){
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
        totalSupply=nftContract.totalSupply();
  
      }
     } catch (error) {
       
     }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSupplyAtStart();
  }
```

**Error**

Failed to compile.

```
./src/components/Home/index.js
SyntaxError: /Users/ekutlugun/Desktop/anti-ape-front/src/components/Home/index.js: Missing semicolon. (50:21)

  48 |      }
  49 |   }
> 50 |   componentDidMount() {
     |                      ^
  51 |     this.getSupplyAtStart();
  52 |   }
  53 |
```

Comment: The code doesn't make sense? Is this code mean to be inside another component?

Comment: What's the context of this in componentDidMount(). For now it looks like two functions with nothing in common

Comment: What you have is simply invalid JavaScript syntax. You have a function declaration immediately followed by a method declaration. But those two things can't be in the same place. A method declaration is only valid inside an object literal or `class` (you'd want `class` in this case), and function declarations are not valid there. Declare your function outside your `class` and call it from `componentDidMount`, or make it a method (though nothing in it looks like it needs to be a method). There's no shortage of examples of this on the web, I suggest referring to some of them.

Comment: *"...but i can't call "componentDidMount" function at beginning..."* **You** don't. React does, when mounting the component.

Comment: `componentDidMount` can be used in Class Component, not in Functional component.

Comment: Okay, i understood the problem i guess, thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `function` keyword. If you are using class-based components and defining new methods inside class is written without `function` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
getSupplyAtStart = () => {
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      if(ethereum){
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
        totalSupply=nftContract.totalSupply();
  
      }
     } catch (error) {
       
     }
  }
```

ComponentDidMount should be used in class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class Usingdidmount extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
    this.state = {
     name: "React"
};

 }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getSupplyAtStart();
 }

 getSupplyAtStart = () => {
    try {
      const { ethereum } = window;
      if(ethereum){
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum);
        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
        totalSupply=nftContract.totalSupply();
  
      }
     } catch (error) {
       
     }
  }

render() {
const { todos } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <h3>Using componentDidMount for initial data render</h3>
  
  </div>
);
 }
 }

 export default Usingdidmount;
```